# Virtualization software for Reversing

Tags: tools, exploit

What is the best virtualization software for Reverse engineering and exploit development?

Comment: You need to refine a bit your question, right now your scope is way too broad. Try to tell more about your context (is it software or hardware reverse engineering ? what kind of target/usage are you aiming for ? ...).

Comment: Buy IDA Pro. 
Setup a virtual lab with a number of configurations of OS etc (VirtualBox / vmware ESXi).
Setup a Fuzzing lab.

Overal, a bad Question.

Comment: Yeah bad question i think i'll do some more research

Comment: @user3286303: You should at least try to spell virtualization properly once !

Comment: sorry i have a really bad keyboard

Answer (score 2):

You could use Kali which is designed for that purpose. 
http://www.kali.org/ 
You can either install it onto your machine or use VM to execute it or even use it as LiveCD.